# Workgroup DNS server can't register workgroup client

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running both DHCP and DNS roles and a client machine (Windows 7). DHCP is configured with 003, 006 and 015 options and the win7 machine is successfully configured with DHCP but the win7 machine dose not register itself in DNS. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a default route (you're using DHCP) you need to include 249 Classless Static Routes.